# Number of seconds since the beginning of the day UTC timezone

Tags: python, utc, timedelta, seconds

How do I find "number of seconds since the beginning of the day UTC timezone" in Python? I looked at the docs and didn't understand how to get this using `datetime.timedelta`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

```
from datetime import datetime, time

utcnow = datetime.utcnow()
midnight_utc = datetime.combine(utcnow.date(), time(0))
delta = utcnow - midnight_utc
print delta.seconds # <-- careful
```

**EDIT** As suggested, if you want microsecond precision, or potentially crossing a 24-hour period (i.e. delta.days > 0),  use `total_seconds()` or the formula given by @unutbu.

```
print delta.total_seconds()  # 2.7
print delta.days * 24 * 60 * 60 + delta.seconds + delta.microseconds / 1e6 # < 2.7
```

Comment: use [`delta.total_seconds()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072740/pythonnumber-of-seconds-since-the-beginning-of-the-day-utc-timezone/8072776#8072776)

Comment: If he/she knows it's < 24 hours since the beginning of the day, it's safe to use `timedelta.seconds` correct?  Just wondering if there's another reason to avoid it for this answer.

Comment: [Leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) are not supported so it is safe to assume that `delta.days` is `0`. But `.total_seconds()` is better semantically and it is a less burden for a reader of the code.

Answer (score 7):

The number of seconds in a `datetime.timedelta`, `x`, is given by [timedelta.total_seconds](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds):

```
x.total_seconds()
```

This function was introduced in Python2.7. For older versions of python, you just have to compute it yourself: `total_seconds = x.days*24*60*60 + x.seconds + x.microseconds/1e6`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
t = time.gmtime()
seconds_since_utc_midnight = t.tm_sec + (t.tm_min * 60) + (t.tm_hour * 3600)
```

for localtime, we can use `time.localtime()` instead of `time.gmtime()`