# Python - is there a function that returns the seconds passed of each day

Tags: python

I have a Python script which runs as a continuous service for long time (days, month ...).  From time to time data from the serial port comes in. These values were calculated and stored in a database. Everything is ok so far.

Now I want to extend the script a bit. Therefore I am looking for a built in method from e.g. datetime .., which returns the **past seconds of each day as an Integer value**  when the data comes in. There is no need for timezone, epoche...

For a other reason I just use something like this "`t = time.strftime('%H:%M')`". This works.

But, can I get the **seconds as Int in one step**? Must I calculate it by myself? Or have I overseen something in the docs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of seconds since the beginning of the day UTC timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072740/number-of-seconds-since-the-beginning-of-the-day-utc-timezone)

Comment: Leap seconds and daylight savings time (which is related to time zones) aside, *every* day has 86,400 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it. I don't know if you count the modulo operator as a second step.

```
int(time.time()) % 86400
```

That gives elapsed seconds since 00h00 UTC today. You'll have to add an offset for the timezone you are in if you want it to show wall-clock time. And I suppose that might count as another step.

Comment: thank you for this helpfull answer. I tried this in above way and added the offset of my timezone. I got the expected value on a very short way.

Comment: If you liked the solution please accept the answer.